# Streaming from thousands of instances to a web server - Windows Application

Tags: c#, windows, stream, streaming

I have a very complex goal to achieve and I need the help of a streaming master.

Here's the scenario:

- Run a thousand instances of a windows application (game) on a windows 10 machine.
- Attach a thousand streaming services (probably implemented on c#) to each of the running application instances (each window is attached to a single streaming service)
- Send video packets of the stream to a web server (each stream will have it's own id)
- Using a web browser, watch a specific stream (by id, live, on demand)

Questions:

1. I know I can run multiple instances of the game on a windows machine, **is running a thousand instances of the application** **(the application is fairly lightweight)** **even possible?** if so, what kind of hardware will I need?
2. Performance-wise, **is it possible to broadcast a thousand instances of streams from a single machine** or am I going completely overboard here?

***To summarize, I need to run a thousand instances of a windows application and stream video from each instance for web clients to watch.***

I have a windows software (written in c#) to run the instances of the windows application and a Node.JS based web server + front end to watch streams. My issue is Scale ability. Any help would be appreciated.